# Stacking div over floating div without content wrapping?

Tags: html, css

I have one element (a div) floating to the right of content, and below the content (which can be varying in height) I have another div that I want to stack above the floated right div, but stay below the content.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/8nap0qm6/

While this is close, I need the content within the ".over" div to not wrap when it hits that right-hand div, but instead fill up the whole ".over" div while still overlapping the right-hand div.

Putting a "clear: both/left" on the ".over" div pushes the div below the right-hand div instead of overlapping it.

I know I could absolute position the over div:

```
.over {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px; // or xx%
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

but I need it to be vertically controlled by the content so I can't put a set "top" on it.

Is there a way to achieve this? (Make white text in blue box go full width of blue box.) I'm open to using completely different code if necessary.

Comment: Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/8nap0qm6/8/

Comment: Maybe [this](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/8nap0qm6/2/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to set `position: absolute;`

```
.over {
position: absolute;
z-index: 5;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8nap0qm6/12/)

Comment: Except I need the ".over" div to actually go over top of the ".right" div. So like my jsfiddle, but with the contents of the ".over" div going the full width of the div.

Answer (score 2):

As the given answers don't seem to satisfy exactly what's expected, I decided to change some things to make the output closer to what you expect. [Check my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8nap0qm6/11/).

Major changes:

1) Added a `#parent` div to wrap the whole content

2) Absolutely positioned the `.right` div, relative to `#parent`

3) Added width to `.right` and all `#parent`'s `p` elements so that summing both results in 100%

Answer (score 1):

Just add `clear: both;` to your `.over` class:

```
.over{
    clear: both;
    /* your properties */
}
```